# Firebase admin auth list users does not return all users in the project

Tags: firebase-admin

the userList result contains only one userRecord while all the users are around 8

```
corsHandler(request, response, () => {
        admin.auth().listUsers(10, 'token')
            .then((UserListResult) => {

                if (UserListResult.pageToken) { console.log('is found') }
                response.status(200).send(UserListResult)
            })
            .catch(error => response.send(error))
    })
```

Comment: I have the same issue here. Any sugestions?

Comment: I have the same issue here as well.

Answer (score -1):

Finally, I resolved this.

It seems that if the pageToken is a null or an invalid string, it returns just one record (based on a couple of tests, last user record)

I changed my code as below and it is working

```
import * as express from 'express'
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'
import { validate } from '../middleware/auth.middleware';

const router = express.Router()

/** List users */
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    let { limit, page } = req.query

    limit = parseInt(limit) || 25;
    page = page === 'null' ? null : page;

    try {
        // Adding a conditional operator here, one with pageToken & other with just limit
        const users: admin.auth.ListUsersResult = page ? await admin.auth().listUsers(limit, page || null) : await admin.auth().listUsers(limit);
        const nextPageToken: string = users.pageToken;

        res.status(200).json({ message: 'Success', users: [...users.users], nextPageToken }).end();
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal Server Error' }).end();
    }
});

export { router }
```